# product is not deleting from cart

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to delete product from cart but its not deleting , any suggestion to fix it,when i click on submit button then it says **404|not found**

**controller:**

```
public function deleteCartProduct(Product $product)
{
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->delProduct($product);
    Session::put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->route('product.cart')->with('flash_message_success', 'Product product has been removed from Cart');
}
```

**model**

```
public function deleteProduct($product)
{
    if ($this->contents) {
        if (array_key_exists($product->product_slug, $this->contents)) {
            $delProduct = $this->contents[$product->slug];
            $this->totalQty -= $delProduct['qty'];
            $this->totalPrice -= $delProduct['price'];
            array_forget($this->contents, $product->slug);
        }
    }
}
```

blade file

```
    @foreach($contents as $slug => $cartItem)
                      <form action="{{ route('deleteCartProduct', $product) }}" method="POST">
                          @csrf
                        <tr class="table-row">
                            <td class="column-1">
                                <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
                                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/product_images/{{ $cartItem['product']->product_image }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column-2">{{ $cartItem['product']->product_name }}</td>
                            <td class="column-3">${{ $cartItem['product']->product_price }}</td>
                            <td class="column-4">
                                <div class="flex-w bo5 of-hidden w-size17">
                                    <button class="btn-num-product-down color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                                        <i class="fs-12 fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>

                                    <input class="size8 m-text18 t-center num-product" type="number" name="num-product1" value="{{ $cartItem['qty'] }}">

                                    <button class="btn-num-product-up color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                                        <i class="fs-12 fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column-5">${{ $cartItem['price'] }}</td>
                            <td class="column-5">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger value="Remove Product">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      </form>
                      @endforeach
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/cart/delete-product/{id}','ProductController@deleteCartProduct')->name('deleteCartProduct');
```

Comment: In the model, you have defined `deleteProduct` method and then in the controller, you have used `$cart->delProduct($product);` methods. So need to change method name in the controller like `$cart->deleteProduct($product);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route should be `Route::delete` instead of `Route::get` and then in the form add this as well:

```
@method('delete')
```

I saw your error on the button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger value="Remove Product">
```

Change it with this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove Product">
```

Missing quote..

**EDIT**

Your route should be this:

```
Route::delete('/cart/delete-product/{id}','Admin\ProductController@deleteCartProduct')->name('deleteCartProduct');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201205/discussion-on-answer-by-nakov-product-is-not-deleting-from-cart).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code in a controller as below.

```
public function deleteCartProduct(Product $product)
{
     $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
     $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
     $cart->deleteProduct($product);
     Session::put('cart', $cart);

     return redirect()->route('product.cart')->with('flash_message_success', 'Product product has been removed from Cart');
}
```

Comment: nthing changes when i click on del btn then it goes to this url 127.0.0.1:8000/cart/delete-product and shows 404 notfound

Comment: this is my btn <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger value="Remove Product"> but it shows like this:  https://ibb.co/ZhskxzT

Comment: actually the problem is in button this is my btn <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger value="Remove Product"> but it shows like this: ibb.co/ZhskxzT

Answer (score 0):

You defined it as method="POST" in blade. and "get" in route. So you need to change verb to Route::post

Comment: actually the problem is in button this is my btn <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger value="Remove Product"> but it shows like this: ibb.co/ZhskxzT